# How can I use one table design structure of one database into another database table structure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have 2 database call CUSTOMER_NEW and CUSTOMER_OLD.
I want to use on table that is cust_info's design in CUSTOMER_NEW table without recreating all the field again.
And I want to do this by any method other than writing a code of using that table in that new database..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into customer_new.newtable from customer_old.originaltable
```

Comment: where should i write this code can u tell me..i am using sql server 2008 management studio for db creation

Comment: `New Query` button, copy and paste the code, change names to you need and run with `F5`